# Accept only letters and capitalize first character in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need an EditText to only allow letters and capitalize the first character.

To only allow letters, I set the property 
`android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "` in the XML layout and it worked properly. Then, I also set the property `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` to capitalize the first letter, but it didn't work.

Just to know what was going on I tried to remove the digits property and then the textCapSentences property worked fine.

So, **the thing is**: I can use one property or the other, but I can't get them both working at the same time. How can I solve this? May I need to solve it programmatically? Thanks.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:hint="@string/et_hint" />
```

Comment: Why not just capitalize the first letter yourself, when you go to use the value in the `EditText`?

Comment: @EliseoBaoSouto you need to capitalize each word? Or each new sentence?

Comment: @AlexeyDenysenko I need to capitalize the first character. I also tried `android:inputType="textCapWords"` but it behaved in the same way.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need the EditText to display the first character in caps while typing.

Comment: "I need the EditText to display the first character in caps while typing" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the textCapSentences property and do the letter checking programatically like this:

```
et_name.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter }); 

InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
    for (int i = start;i < end;i++) { 
        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(0))) { 
            return ""; 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about using the two properties together, but if one works by itself one solution could be to use textCapSentences on your EditText and code a text filter, like so:

```
public static InputFilter[] myFilter = new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) &&
                        source.charAt(i) != '@' &&
                        source.charAt(i) != '#') {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Invalid character: " + source.charAt(i));
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

This example accepts 0-9, all letters (upper and lowercase), as well as the charcters @ and #, just to give an example. If you try to enter any other character it will return "", and essentially ignore it.

Apply it when initializing the Edit Text:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    editText.setFilters(myFilter);
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the if condition to filter numbers and it did the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want you to capitalize each new **word**, you should use another inputType:

```
 android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

If you want to capitalize the first **letter** of each new **sentence**, you can add `.` to your digits, it will help system recognize new sentence:

```
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. "
```

Comment: I tried it and it's not working for me. I don't know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple values for an attribute like this `android:inputType="textCapSentences|text"` Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's not possible to filter the number this way, and it required.

Comment: Try using  `android:imputType="textPersonName"`